# How does one keep a file's timestamp (date modified) after a logrotate?

Tags: linux, logrotate, timestamp

Title says it all, I have a log rotate set up daily for some rather large log files. Sometimes we can generate 3 of these a day, sometimes we only generate 1, they're each about 500MB. Is there a way to keep date modified of the file after a log rotate? It's a lot easier to note those dates at a glance when looking for something in the logs, than to head and tail each file looking for dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure log rotate to append the date to rotated log files (by specifying dateext option).

Answer (score 2):

Two options immediately spring to mind:

- You make logrotate append the date to rotated log files, by using the option `dateext`. If you're doing the rotation shortly after midnight, you may want the log file to have the name of the previous day; you can do this with the option `dateyesterday`.
- You can use the `postrotate` to run a command, such as `touch -m yesterday` after the file has been rotated, to change the file's modify time to the previous day.

`man logrotate.conf` and `info coreutils 'touch invocation'` are good places to start looking for more information.